# Is there a more elegant way to read the numbers from the input stream?

Tags: c#

I have the following test-client code in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int N = StdIn.readInt(); // Read number of sites.
  while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
  {
     int p = StdIn.readInt();
     int q = StdIn.readInt();
  }
}
```

And in C#:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   string input;
   while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       int p = Convert.ToInt32(input);
       int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   }
}
```

I'm new in C#. Please, help me, is there a more elegant way to read the numbers from the input stream ? For example, how to simulate `while (!StdIn.isEmpty())` more accurately in C# ?

Comment: Why do you think your code is not enough _elegant_? And wouldn't be better in [CodeReview.SE] at least?

Comment: isEmpty is closer to KeyAvailable I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `TryParse` method rather than `Convert.ToInt32` because it doesn't throw `System.FormatException` when failed to convert. It also returns the  bool result of the conversion operation.

`IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is somewhat 'more elegant' way to check the string value :

```
        int n, p, q;
        string input;

        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);            

        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((input = Console.ReadLine())))
        {                
            Int32.TryParse(input, out p);
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out q);                
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```